# Send iOS push notification via Parse with hurl.it test

Tags: ios, json, parse-platform, push

I am trying to send push notifications to my iOS test client. I have the app set up properly and can receive push notifications. The problem I'm trying to solve is that the custom field is not being received: it is like it is being filtered out.

I am build my app with Corona SDK and I believe I have the config.lua set up properly. I have create the appropriate certificates etc and the notifications do get received. The custom field does not.

I am trying to send custom data via the push using hurl.it but cannot figure out the correct JSON content to send. I understand the format - it's the content I need.

Can anyone help me configure the form properly? Currently I am sending to URL:
https://api.parse.com/1/push/

And the POST body is:

```
{"data":{"badge":"Increment","custom":"gumbo","alert":"This is a test message from tester1@mailinator.com","title":"This is a test message from "},"channels":["Atester2_mailinator_com"]}
```

The "custom" value is being received as "custom":[]

Comment: this may happen because the Data type for `custom` might be an array. and you are passing `string`. Try sending `"custom":"['gumbo']"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in "custom" being a string. The type here must be table.